# Align textbox and button

Tags: html

I have two textbox and one button in a popupbox. 
        I want to make button exactly below the two textbox , 
        wherein in my code it is not happening. **Please help**
        HTML COde :::

```
<form method="post" action="index.html">
            <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
            <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
        <p class="remember_me">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
                    Remember me on this computer
            </label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Logine" class="marginleft5"></p>
            <!-- <div class="login-help">
                <p>Forgot your password? <a href="#.html">Click here to reset it</a>.</p>
            </div>  -->    
 </form>
```

Comment: It is below the text boxes http://jsfiddle.net/46C3b/

Comment: Please provide a screenshot, as the output of the html is coming as you require. Also post the related css.

Comment: some css would be a great help

Answer (score -1):

Use `<div>` tags for lines, or otherwise use `<br/>` to break line